# Свойство делегата возвращает nil

Tags: ios, swift, делегаты

Не могу разобраться почему свойство делегата возвращает `nil`

Есть `xib` ячейка, которая инициализируется в классе `NewPlaceTableViewController`, ячейка имеет внутри себя `UIStackView`, со своим классом `RatingControl`, в котором присутствует реализация кастомного рейтинга.

Мне нужно из класса `RatingControl` передать значения свойства `rating` в `NewPlaceTableViewController` что бы записать в базу данных `realm` через переменную `currentRating`

```
let newPlace = FavoritePlace(name: placeNameTextField.text!,
location: placeLocationTextField.text,
type: placeTypeTextField.text, imageData: imageData, 
rating: Double(currentRating))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

протокол

```
protocol RatingProtocol: class {
    var currentRating: Int { get set }
}
```

класс  `RatingControl`

```
@IBDesignable class RatingControl: UIStackView {

    var delegate: RatingProtocol?

    // MARK: - Preperties
    var rating = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateButtonSelectionState()
        }
    }
    private var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()
    @IBInspectable var startSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 44.0, height: 44.0) {
        didSet {
            setupView()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var startCount: Int = 5 {
        didSet {
            setupView()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Initialization
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
//        newPlace?.delegate = self
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupView()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    // MARK: - Button Action
    @objc func ratingButtonAction(button: UIButton) {
        guard let index = ratingButtons.firstIndex(of: button) else { return }
        let selectedRating = index + 1

        if selectedRating == rating {
            rating = 0
        } else {
            rating = selectedRating
        }
        print("rating \(rating)")
        delegate?.currentRating = rating
        print("currentRating \(delegate?.currentRating)")
    }

    // MARK: - Private Methods
    private func setupView() {
        for button in ratingButtons {
            removeArrangedSubview(button)
            button.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        ratingButtons.removeAll()

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let emptyStar = UIImage(named: "emptyStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)
        let filledStar = UIImage(named: "filledStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)
        let highlithedStar = UIImage(named: "highlithedStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)

        for _ in 0..<startCount {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setImage(emptyStar, for: .normal)
            button.setImage(filledStar, for: .selected)
            button.setImage(highlithedStar, for: .highlighted)
            button.setImage(highlithedStar, for: [.highlighted, .selected])

            button.setSize(width: startSize.width, height: startSize.height)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            addArrangedSubview(button)
            ratingButtons.append(button)
        }
        updateButtonSelectionState()
    }

    private func updateButtonSelectionState() {
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerated() {
            button.isSelected = index < rating
        }
    }
}
```

класс `NewPlaceTableViewController` который реализовывает протокол и через свойство `currentRating` передается в базу данных, метод `savePlace`

```
class NewPlaceTableViewController: UITableViewController, RatingProtocol {

    var currentRating = 0

    let newPlaceImageCellId = "newPlaceImageCellId"
    let newPlaceNameCellId = "newPlaceNameCellId"
    let newPlaceLocationCellId = "newPlaceLocationCellId"
    let newPlaceTypeCellId = "newPlaceTypeCellId"
    let newPlaceRatingCellId = "newPlaceRatingCellId"

    let placeCellHeaderData: [PlaceCellHeaderData] = PlaceCellHeaderData.fetchData()
    var imageIsChanged = false
    var currentPlace: FavoritePlace?
    var ratingControl: RatingControl?
    var ratingCell: NewPlaceRatingTableViewCell?
    var countCell = 5

    let titleHeader: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
        label.text = "Favorite Places"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    var placeNameTextField: UITextField = {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return textfield
    }()

    var placeLocationTextField: UITextField = {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return textfield
    }()

    var placeTypeTextField: UITextField = {
        let textfield = UITextField()
        textfield.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        return textfield
    }()

    let placeImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Photo"))
        return imageView
    }()

    var saveBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        return barButton
    }()

    var cancelBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        return barButton
    }()

    var undoBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        return barButton
    }()

//    var ratingControl: RatingControl = {
//        let rating = RatingControl()
//        return rating
//    }()
//
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupTableView()
        setupNavigation()
        ratingControl?.delegate = self
    }

    func setupTableView() {
        let placeImageNib = UINib(nibName: NewPlaceImageTableViewCell.identifier, bundle: nil)
        let placeNameNib = UINib(nibName: NewPlaceNameTableViewCell.identifier, bundle: nil)
        let placeLocationNib = UINib(nibName: NewPlaceLocationTableViewCell.identifier, bundle: nil)
        let placeTypeNib = UINib(nibName: NewPlaceTypeTableViewCell.identifier, bundle: nil)
        let placeRatingNib = UINib(nibName: NewPlaceRatingTableViewCell.identifier, bundle: nil)

        tableView.register(placeImageNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: newPlaceImageCellId)
        tableView.register(placeNameNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: newPlaceNameCellId)
        tableView.register(placeTypeNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: newPlaceTypeCellId)
        tableView.register(placeLocationNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: newPlaceLocationCellId)
        tableView.register(placeRatingNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: newPlaceRatingCellId)

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    func setupNavigation() {
        navigationItem.titleView = titleHeader
        if currentPlace == nil {
            cancelBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction))
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBarButtonItem
        }
        saveBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(saveAction))
        saveBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveBarButtonItem
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countCell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let index = indexPath.item-1

        switch indexPath.item  {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newPlaceImageCellId, for: indexPath) as! NewPlaceImageTableViewCell
            setupEditScreen(placeImage: placeImageView, name: nil, location: nil, type: nil)
            cell.placeImageView.image = placeImageView.image
            configureCell(cell)
            return cell

        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newPlaceNameCellId, for: indexPath)  as! NewPlaceNameTableViewCell
            placeNameTextField = cell.placeNameTextField
            setupEditScreen(placeImage: nil, name: placeNameTextField, location: nil, type: nil)
            configureCell(cell)
            cell.placeNameTextField.delegate = self
            cell.placeTextLabel.text = placeCellHeaderData[index].title
            cell.placeNameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)
            return cell

        case 2:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newPlaceLocationCellId, for: indexPath)  as! NewPlaceLocationTableViewCell
            placeLocationTextField = cell.placeLocationTextField
            setupEditScreen(placeImage: nil, name: nil, location: placeLocationTextField, type: nil)
            cell.placeLocationTextField.delegate = self
            cell.placeTextLabel.text = placeCellHeaderData[index].title
            configureCell(cell)
            return cell

        case 3:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newPlaceTypeCellId, for: indexPath)  as! NewPlaceTypeTableViewCell
            placeTypeTextField = cell.placeTypeTextField
            setupEditScreen(placeImage: nil, name: nil, location: nil, type: placeTypeTextField)
            cell.placeTypeTextField.delegate = self
            cell.placeTextLabel.text = placeCellHeaderData[index].title
            configureCell(cell)
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newPlaceRatingCellId, for: indexPath)  as! NewPlaceRatingTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
            cell.directionalLayoutMargins = .zero
//            ratingControl.rating = cell.ratingControl.rating
            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let cameraIcon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "camera")
            let photoIcon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "photo")

            let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            let photoFromCamera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { _ in
                self.chooseImagePicker(source: .camera)
            }

            let photoFromGallery = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo", style: .default) { _ in
                self.chooseImagePicker(source: .photoLibrary)
            }

            photoFromCamera.setValue(cameraIcon, forKey: "image")
            photoFromCamera.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
            photoFromGallery.setValue(photoIcon, forKey: "image")
            photoFromGallery.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)

            actionSheet.addAction(photoFromCamera)
            actionSheet.addAction(photoFromGallery)
            actionSheet.addAction(cancel)
            present(actionSheet, animated:  true)

        } else {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
              return 250
        case 1...3:
            return 75
        default:
            return 140
        }
    }

    private func configureCell(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
    }

    private func setupEditScreen(placeImage: UIImageView?, name: UITextField?, location: UITextField?, type: UITextField?) {
        if currentPlace != nil {
            setupNavigationBar()
            imageIsChanged = true
            guard let data = currentPlace?.imageData, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
            placeImage?.image = image
            name?.text = currentPlace?.name
            location?.text = currentPlace?.location
            type?.text = currentPlace?.type
        }
    }

    private func setupNavigationBar() {
        undoBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .undo, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = undoBarButtonItem
        titleHeader.text = currentPlace?.name
        saveBarButtonItem.isEnabled = true
    }

    func savePlace() {
        var image: UIImage?

        if imageIsChanged {
            image = placeImageView.image
        } else {
            image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "not-pace")
        }
//        let rating = ratingDelegate?.rating
        let imageData = image?.pngData()
        let newPlace = FavoritePlace(name: placeNameTextField.text!, location: placeLocationTextField.text, type: placeTypeTextField.text, imageData: imageData, rating: Double(currentRating))
        print("rating in model \(currentRating)")
        if currentPlace != nil {
            try! realm.write {
                currentPlace?.name = newPlace.name
                currentPlace?.location = newPlace.location
                currentPlace?.type = newPlace.type
                currentPlace?.imageData = newPlace.imageData
                currentPlace?.rating = newPlace.rating
            }
        } else {
            StorageManager.shared.saveObject(newPlace)
        }
    }

    @objc private func cancelAction(_ : UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc private func saveAction(_ : UIButton) {
        savePlace()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadBeforeSaveToRealm"), object: nil)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc private func textFieldChanged() {
        if placeNameTextField.text?.isEmpty == false {
            saveBarButtonItem.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            saveBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Проект https://github.com/Constantine1995/MyFavoritePlaces

При добавлении нового места через "+" снизу есть рейтинг, он и должен записываться в БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

понял, я должен был свойство `delegate = self` не у экземпляра `var ratingControl: RatingControl?` вызывать, а в ячейке `cell.delegate = self`